# Kendo UI issues in IE9

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I am able to read the  value `e.event.target.dataset.row` for the below **data-role** using chrome and mozilla but it is not working in IE 9 which throws the error

**SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'row': object is null or undefined 
IndexController.js, line 202 character 3 using Kendo UI**

```
<a data-role="button" class="hyperlink" data-click="onAccountClick" data-account="#=data.Account_Id#" data-as-of-date="#=data.DEALING_DATE#" data-fund="#=data.FUND_NAME#">#=Account_Id#</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use use currentTarget property like

```js
var target = event.target || event.currentTarget;
var row = target.dataset.row;
```